# Vue.js variable not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, reactive-programming

I am having trouble a variable in vue.js.

Scenario - when a user logs in, I want to set a `loggedIn` variable to `true` and set it to `false` when the user logs out. My code:

index.js:

```
export default {

  state: {
    loggedIn  : false
  },

  login() {
    var self = this;
    var creds = {
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: '/login',
      type: 'POST',
      data: creds,
      success: function(response) {
        self.state.loggedIn = true;
        alert('Logged in!!');
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Error logging in!');
      }
    });
  },
}
```

App.vue:

```
import auth from './index.js';

module.exports = {

  data: function () {

    return {

      loggedIn: auth.state.loggedIn,
    }

  },

  watch: {
    loggedIn: function () {
      alert('loggedIn value has changed!!!');
    }
  },

}
```

As you can see, in `App.vue`, my `loggedIn` variable depends on what's imported from `index.js`. However, it doesn't appear that `loggedIn` in `App.vue` is reactive to `loggedIn` in `index.js`.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make some data reactive, you must set it as the `data` of a component.

Since `auth.state.loggedIn` holds a primitive (a Boolean), assigning its value to `data.loggedIn` simply *copies* it over to `data.loggedIn`.

So while `data.loggedIn` *is* reactive, `auth.state.loggedIn` is not. The two are simply never linked up.

---

The only way to make this work is to assign the whole `state` object to your data:

```js
module.exports = {
  data () {
    return {
      auth: auth.state,
    }

  },

  watch: {
    'auth.loggedIn' () {
      alert('loggedIn value has changed!!!');
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: PERFECT! Bless your soul!